# Dealing with multiple Connections in SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, sql, sqlalchemy

I realize that a `Connection` is created when calling the function `sqlalchemy.create_engine()`. But if I need to create another connection using `connection = engine.connect()`, so that I can eventually insert multiple rows into a Table Object via `connection.execute()` isn't this going to result in a `Connection is busy with results for another hstmt (0)` Error? I passed `poolclass=QueuePool` as an argument in `sqlalchemy.create_engine()` so that the details of building the pool would be handled. However, I still get the same error. Is there a way around this?

Comment: `sqlalchemy` defines a connection pool of 5 connections by default. You can open 2 connections with no problem. `In [6]:
c1 = schema_mgr.engine.connect()
c2 = schema_mgr.engine.connect()
r1 = c1.execute("select count(*) from tweet")
for r in r1:
    print r
r2 = c2.execute("select count(*) from tuser")
for r in r2:
    print r`. Must be something related to your environment? What versions are you using? Can you post your code?